# Why do battery cells fail in groups?

Tags: batteries, battery-chemistry

I have been observing for a long time that battery cells seem to fail in groups that are in close proximity.

I agree that observing 3 cells in a flash-light is not a very ample set, but I recently had the chance to observe several boxes with close manufacturing dates that have held sets of about 100 cells each (in close proximity) and in which several failed. All batteries with expiry date way into the future:

[image: Batteries failing together]

In all sets one could observe one battery failing bad and the others next to it following in the same path, as if one was acting as catalyst in the process.

Is it known why this happens in this way?

Comment: Could it be temperature-related failure?

Comment: This looks like leaking batteries. I guess the acid leaking from one battery is damaging the others.

Comment: Have you tested all batteries in the set to make sure that they have all actually failed?  Could it be that only one failed, but the others just appear failed because of chemical leakage?

Comment: What is their comparative state of charge at the point before they fail?

Comment: @rdtsc absolutely not. They weere kept in the same room, so same temperature and humidity.

Comment: @Autistic I understand what you want to convey, batteries consists of several cells and these are just one. I would still go with battery.

Comment: @Theodore I did not test *all* but quite a few sample and mostr of them were good except the ones where acid was leaking.

Comment: @EugeneSh. How does 'leaking from one battery is damaging the others' nearby? I would expect that if the acid were liquid that it would damage the ones _underneath_ and if it was gas it would damege _all_ in the box -- not exactly th ones nearby.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica The ones away from the damage-area were good, and the ones close to the damage-area were starting to fail.

Comment: @PauloNey How do you decide what is "underneath" in a flashlight, that I presume can have any orientation? This stuff is highly corrosive and can damage the things it is touching. And yes, it is liquid when leaking, then it is drying out and becoming this white goo.

Comment: In a flash-light there is no way to decide. In this particular case they have been stored in boxes -- no movement -- for over two years, and you can really tell what is up and what is down ...

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstood what you meant by "proximity" in your question... Are you saying the failing groups are somehow isolated from each other (to an extent)?

Comment: Are they just stored or electricity connected?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite they are just stored.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, they fail in groups isolated from one another.

Comment: Seems to me that the flashlight or how it's used or what it's subject to might be the culprit here.

Comment: Only the left side battery has a silver ring. The right side battery says Fabrique en Chine. My Chinese Duracell Ni-MH batteries have a very low capacity and become discharged long before my much higher capacity Japanese Energizer ones. But the same price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> several boxes with close manufacturing dates that have held sets of
> about 100 cells each (in close proximity) and in which several failed.
> All batteries with expiry date way into the future

Properly stored Alkaline cells should not fail, so if you have several that did then there is a problem - perhaps defective manufacturing (fake cells?) or improper storage.

However as the saying goes "One rotten apple spoils the whole barrel". An alkaline cell is more likely to leak when discharged, due to build up of hydrogen gas which makes it vent. One cell may have high self discharge, or the electrolyte might eat away part of the case, or the seal might be defective. In either case the result may be electrolyte leakage. The leaked electrolyte is conductive, so it can discharge adjacent cells and make them leak too. This may be why you see clusters of failed cells.

Due to the increased chance of leakage, alkaline cells should not be left in a device when they are nearly flat. Some devices draw a small current all the time (even when 'off') eventually discharging the cells, with a similar risk. The worst case scenario is if the device is accidentally left turned on, when the chance of leakage is much higher. Therefore it is best to remove the cells from the device before putting it into storage.

Comment: I think you nailed it with "The leaked electrolyte is conductive, so it can discharge adjacent cells and make them leak too", that seems to be the most plausible reason for them to fauil in clusters.

Comment: ...The electrolyte seems to be a high viscosity liquid, so that may explain why it spreads only to 'nearby' cells.